# Trying to use Webdriver Manager on Raspberry Pi, am getting error "Could not get version for Firefox with this command: Firefox --version"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, raspberry-pi

Am running a python script that opens up a Firefox tab on my Raspberry Pi

My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

When I try to run the code the webdriver manager shows up like this,

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
```

then says

```
Illegal Instruction
```

Followed by the traceback and ends with a message saying "ValueError: Could not get version for Firefox with this command: Firefox --version". How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing some of the error chain which makes it a bit harder to troubleshoot. When I got the message "Could not get version for Firefox with this command: Firefox --version" part of the error message directed me to a missing package. Which package is missing for you is dependent upon the rest of the error message. I don't remember exactly which missing package fixed my problem, but the below command resolved it.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  fonts-liberation libappindicator3-1 libasound2 libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
  libnspr4 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils libxss1 libdbus-glib-1-2
```

Answer (score 0):

It my be too late to answer this but IMO webdrivermanger brings in linux64 bits and not the ARM64 bits.